# Reading values from txt file to use with copy-item

Tags: powershell

Some help would be great please, I have a text file which is `config.txt` with the following values inside

```
[Paths]
Sourcepath="y:\enterprise\team\input"
TempPath="y:\enterprise\team\temp"
DestPath="y:\enterprise\team\Output"
```

I wanted to have a script that reads from the config file and moves any files from one destination and copies it to the next

```
copy-item 'sourcepath' destination = temppath
```

New to powershell so any help would be great!

Comment: `config.txt` is in INI format, so you want to parse it like that and get the path from the resulting hashtable. PowerShell code for parsing INI files is trivial to find.

Comment: Your Copy-Item command is malformed, take a look at the documentation for [Copy-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) to find out how to use the command correctly. The [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item#examples) within the documentation will also help you.

Answer (score 1):

[Use PowerShell to Work with Any INI File](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/)

You can use this function.

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath
    {
        “^\[(.+)\]” # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        “^(;.*)$” # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = “Comment” + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        } 
        “(.+?)\s*=(.*)” # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To pull the information into PowerShell you need to import the data.  For a plain text file **Get-Content** is the typical method.  As noted in another answer, the text file is in an INI format and so you'll need to manipulate it in order to have it be usable in your script.

One question would be, are you using the config.txt file for other purposes?  If it's only for this one script, then I'd recommend just declaring the three paths in as variables in the main script.

If it's used for other systems and needs to stay in that format, you'll need to figure out how to parse each line.  **Get-Content** will pull it in as an array so you can go through each line.

If it's used for other systems and you can change the format, I recommend switching to a CSV with each column being a different path name.  Then if you use **Import-CSV**  you can do $variable.SourcePath, $variable.TempPath, and $variable.DestPath.